# Show trailing zeros automatically in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, csv, formatting, excel-2010

I want excel to show 625 as 625.00
I don't really want to select the cell and go to format and manually do everything.
My .csv file will be having "625.00", so how can I set Excel 2010 to do this automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. If you are using the Import Wizard, tell the Wizard that the field is text and the .CSV format will be preserved.
2. Use a VBA macro to import the .CSV file and have the macro perform the required formatting.

Comment: Well. I need to select each column to set as text. Is there any way to select all columns and set to text ?

Comment: YES...When you get to step #3, click on the first column and then, while hold down the SHFT key, click on the last column.  This selects ALL the columns.  Then select Text.